# p:dataExporter PDF export no euro sign

Tags: csv, pdf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 6.1 `p:dataExporter` to export `p:dataTable` content into PDF, CSV and XML.

The `p:dataTable` column headers contain German-Umlauts (äöüß) and Euro-Sign. While the Umlauts are exported correctly, the Euro-Sign is shown as `?` in the PDF export. In CSV all characters are shown correctly!

For encoding I tried `ISO-8859-1`, `LATIN1`, `UTF8` - all with the same result.

```
<p:dataExporter type="pdf" encoding="ISO-8859-1" target... fileName.../>
```

I'am using MacOS - probably this is the problem?!

Comment: ISO-8859-1 (which essentially is Latin1) does not contain the Euro sign. ISO-8859-15 does, though.

Comment: Thanks for your hint - using ISO-8859-15 shows the Euro sign in PDF also! But why is the Euro sign in CSV present, where I am using UTF-8 for encoding, and not in PDF?

Comment: That's actually why I didn't write this as an answer but merely as a comment: it was obvious that ISO-8859-1 and Latin1 could not work because they did not constrain the Euro symbol but I have no idea why UTF-8 does not work.

Comment: I opened an primefaces issue and will see what happens ;-)

Comment: @raho Linking the issue would help others with a similar problem with further research.

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2363